# Formatting date "day dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: formatting, compact-framework, .net-2.0

I'm trying to format a date to look this way: "day mm/dd/yyyy" for that I'm using something like : 
`"dddd, " + dateFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern`
The thing is `ShortDatePattern` does seem to be specific to the current culture info. for example I'm getting:
fr_FR : Lundi 27/06/2011
gb_GB : Monday 27/06/2011 when it should be Monday 06/27/2011
I hope I'm being clear.

[Update]
I wanted the string to update automatically between "dd/mm/yyyy" and "mm/dd/yyyy" depending on the current culture and i thought ShortDatePattern didn't do the trick but it actually does! it's just that in en_GB it's still "dd/mm/yyyy"
[/update]

[Resolved]

`DateTime date;

date.ToString("dddd, " + CurrentCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);`

Answer (score 5):

If you *always* want the date pattern to be `MM/dd/yyyy`, then specify that:

```
string format = "dddd, MM/dd/yyyy";
```

Note that the "/" part is also locale-specific; if you want it to always be a forward-slash, you should escape it:

```
string format = "dddd, MM'/'dd'/'yyyy";
```

If that's not what you were looking for, please update your question to make it clear exactly what you're doing (with sample code), the result you're getting, and the result you want.

Comment: The OP wanted dd/MM/yyyy not MM/dd/yyyy. See my answer above.

Comment: @Chris: The last sentence includes: "when it should be Monday 06/27/2011" - in other words, month first. Likewise: "I'm trying to format a date to look this way : "day mm/dd/yyyy""

Comment: sorry you are right. I was looking at the title of the question being dd/mm/yyyy which is obviously the current output rather than desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
DateTime date;
date.ToString("dddd, MM/dd/yyyy");
```